# App callback does not update graph when if condition is used

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am uploading my data to a dash app and created a radioitem to select what kind of graph I want to create from it. For now I only have created one graph function stored in a seperate graph_definitions.py file:

```
def lineplot(dat, testmode=False):
    '''
    testmode: If testomde is set to True only the first 10 items will be used in the graph
    '''     
    print('graph is called')
    cells=list(dat['unique_id'].unique())

    if testmode==True:

        cells=cells[0:10]



    #initiating traces as a list
    traces=[]
    #getting trace IDs from unique IDs (cells)

    #looping through the cells
    for c in cells:   
        print('data looping')
        #appending x, y data based on current cell to the list of traces
        traces.append(go.Scatter(
        x=dat.loc[dat['unique_id']==c]['Location_Center_X_Zeroed'],        
        y=dat.loc[dat['unique_id']==c]['Location_Center_Y_Zeroed']
        )
    )

    print('looping finished')
    return {'data' :traces}
```

For the rest of the code see below.
Now the problem is the following:
The app callback works, all the prints from the graph function are created and seem to be correct, but the graph is not updated.
When I, however omit the if conditioning so that I get

```
def get_value(value):
    print(value)
    print(type(value))
    print(GD.lineplot(df, testmode=True))
    return GD.lineplot(df, testmode=True)
```

It does manage to update the graph as soon as I select a value on the radio items. 
Now I do not want to only have one graph option, but would like to create several graphs and select between them, so this is not much use.
Can anybody explain to me why the if conditions are creating a problem?

```
import base64
import datetime
import io

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table

import pandas as pd
import sys
import os


sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(__file__))
import graph_definitions as GD


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
#%% app upload
global df
df=[]
app.layout = html.Div([

    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Table(id='output-data-upload'),
    dcc.RadioItems(
    options=[
        {'label': 'lineplot', 'value': 'lineplot'},
        {'label': 'None', 'value' : 'None'}

    ],
    value='None',
    id='graph_selector'),
    dcc.Graph(id='migration_data')
])

#%%layouts
def generate_table(df):
    return dash_table.DataTable(
                data=df.to_dict('records'),
                columns=[{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
                fixed_rows={'headers':True, 'data':0},
                style_cell={'width' :'150px'}
            )


#%%
#backup
def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        global df
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])
    #selection of graphs
    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
        html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

        generate_table(df),
        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])

#%% update after upload
@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              [Input('upload-data', 'contents')],
              [State('upload-data', 'filename'),
               State('upload-data', 'last_modified')])
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children
@app.callback(Output('migration_data', 'figure'),
              [Input('graph_selector', 'value')])
def get_value(value):
     print(value)
     if 'df' in globals():
       if value=='lineplot':
             print(GD.lineplot(df, testmode=True))
             return GD.lineplot(df, testmode=True)
```

edit:
I could get around this problem by storing the function in a dictionary and calling it by it's key.

```
graph_options={'lineplot':GD.lineplot}
def get_value(value):
    return graph_options[value](df, testmode=True)
```

In the case that I cannot use if conditioning, this however, will only work if the inputs for all graphs are the same.

Comment: What happens if you only remove `if 'df' in globals():`? I would recommend not using a `global` anyway. You could add the `data` from your table to the callback and still work with the dataframe while avoiding a `global` variable.

Comment: I had tried that but it lead to the same behavior.